# Function Argument Packing And Unpacking Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, ternary-operator

Currently, I have a function like so:

```
def my_func(*args):
    #prints amount of arguments
    print(len(args))
    #prints each argument
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

I want to put multiple arguments through to this function, but the following doesn't work for me. It gives out a syntax error on the asterisk * after the else.

```
my_func(
    *(1, 2, 3, 4)
    if someBool is True
    else *(1, 2)
)
```

The workaround I found puts 1 and 2 in first and then puts 3 and 4 while checking for someBool.

```
my_func(
    1, 2,
    3 if someBool is True else None,
    4 if someBool is True else None
)
```

I am fine with the above as my function checks for None but if there is an alternative I would gladly thank them.

Comment: Why don't you write the `if` statement outside the function call?

Comment: I have a function taking either 2, 4, or any even number of arguments. Making it in one function makes it (for me) easier to check and understand. I would put it outside but I'm more comfortable with the ternary operator. Thanks for the suggestion though :D

Comment: Good tutorial about packing-unpacking arguments https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `*` to outside the `... if ... else ...`:

```
my_func(
    *((1, 2, 3, 4)
      if someBool is True
      else (1, 2))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra set of parenthesis. Also, you don't need to say `is True` to check if a Boolean is "truthy" in python, making it: `my_func(*((1, 2, 3, 4) if someBool else (1, 2)))`.

Comment: The `is True` was included since I wanted to prevent some possible confusion. I'll omit it next time :)